# Should we prefer singular or plural in tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

This being a site about English language, we should be well-equipped to decide about something like this, eh? :)

Should we prefer singular or plural in tags, in cases where both would make sense?

For example:

- [pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronoun) vs. [pronouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronouns)
- [synonym](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonym) vs. [synonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonyms)
- [preposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preposition) vs. [prepositions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositions)

As of September 5th, 2010, the usage is mixed (unsurprisingly).

On the more popular SE sites this is a [well-known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6752/merge-singular-and-plural-tags).

**Edit**: Obviously certain tags (e.g. [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar), [syntax](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax), [writing-style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-style), [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology), [vocabulary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary), [literature](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature), etc.) should be in singular in any case, as plural just wouldn't make much sense—this question is not about such tags.

Comment: I just wanted to register my opinion of “I don’t give a damn, but please feel free to hash this out”

Comment: If you don't care about it then you can either upvote both answers (to get it over with as soon as possible) or downvote both answers (to give more people a chance to vote) or not vote on either.

Comment: @Shinto, @nohat: We don't seem to be getting many more votes (either way)... How about just declaring plural the winner, and starting to do some batch retagging accordingly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Plural

(`verbs`, `nouns`, `synonyms`)

*Putting plural here as an answer for people to vote on.*

Comment: It seems more natural for me using the plural, on the tags used as example. Wikipedia category names usually use the plural (_programming languages_, _programming languages created in 1990_, _Gabonese composers_, _Oakland Athletics seasons_, etc). In some cases, it makes more sense to use the singular: _syntax_ versus _syntaxes_, _style_ versus _styles_, etc.

Comment: If this is decided, someone who has the rep should merge the `indefinite-article` tag into `indefinite-articles` (both are currently in use)

Comment: @keithjgrant: "definite article" and "indefinite article" seem like special cases to me. English only has one of each (unless you count "some" as an article, which I don't think most do) so the singular makes more sense to me.

Answer (score -3):

### Singular

(`verb`, `noun`, `synonym`)

I prefer the singular, and support retagging to make things consistent.

Comment: I support singular, because its an obvious problem with two equally good solutions, and this was the first one.

Comment: Right; since there's some support and no opposing views (personally I might have chosen plural but don't really care either way), I'll mark this as accepted (for now at least), and start retagging accordingly.

Comment: Removed the accepted status of this for now, as plural seems to have gained support. (Though maybe it's just because the large font in the other answer better attracts upvoters... :)