# Too many tags verb/verbs

Tags: discussion, tags

I've arbitrarily retagged six posts tagged "verb" to "verbs" since there were nine posts tagged with "verbs". Tag explosion is happening and taming is required????

Answer (score 2):

Tag explosion is not happening, not yet anyway. You can blame me for the verbs/verb tags.  There was an ongoing retagging from `verbs` to `verb`; see this for background: **[Should we prefer singular or plural in tags?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-we-prefer-singular-or-plural-in-tags)**  (Please participate in that question by voting or adding answers!)

As to why I didn't retag *all* of them at once while at it: well, obviously it's boring as hell, and humans are not made for this kind of work (and I don't have access to automated retag tools). So I started doing it in small batches. (Yes, I know the number of uses was not *that* big :-)

And even though the OP of this question (Shinto Sherlock) reverted the retagging that I started, we should do it again, **unless** plural comes out as the winner in the afore-linked-to question.

Comment: No, no ask them to do it automatically.

Comment: @Shinto: Ah, well, yes. If we can get the attention of someone who can batch retag, that's the best option.

Comment: @Jonik: Go and ask on meta.stackoverflow.com or send an email to Robert Cartiano, etc.

Comment: @Shinto: Ok; I asked Robert.

Comment: Retag to what, though? I can only find [one vote](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/72) on the entire issue. Go to [this post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/160) to nominate some provisional moderators!

Comment: @Robert, the last I looked singular was the sole option with *any* support **and** it was already used for nearly every other tag than `verbs`. (Thanks for retagging btw!) But plural seems to have gained support recently, so let's see what we ultimately go with...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a case for tag synonyms. Of course, with only 9 users above the required 1000 reputation, it might not be easy to get things done -- maybe the threshold should be lowered during beta?

In any case, I think the best option is to post here on Meta before a mass retagging. If enough people approve, it can be retagged *and* get a synonym. I'm sure moderators pass through here now and then to do the dirty work if there aren't enough regular users to do it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the retag rep threshold is lower during beta. I know that I retagged things before I hit 1K rep.

Comment: I'm in the 400s and am retagging fiendishly.

Comment: Umm, is there a "tag synonym" feature in SE software nowadays? Can you point me to a relevant meta discussion or something?

Comment: If such an alias/synonym feature exists, sure, set it up for verb/verbs! As for which one we should use, it depends on the outcome of http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-we-prefer-singular-or-plural-in-tags (I don't see why verb/verbs should be dealt with individually when it's clearly a more common issue.)

Comment: @Jonik: Just look at the new "Info" tab for any tag. ( [example](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=discussion&sort=info&pagesize=15) )

Comment: @Jonik: See http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/info, for example.