# Batch retagging from singular to plural

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

A month ago, I asked [**if we should prefer singular or plural**](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-we-prefer-singular-or-plural-in-tags) in tag names. **Plural** seems to come out as the clear favourite among those who have any opinion on the matter.

Therefore, I'd like to request that at least the following tags are batch retagged (with corresponding tag synonyms) to plural form: `verb` -> `verbs`, etc.

```
verb
word 
synonym
pronoun 
preposition
article 
accent
proper-noun
adjective 
neologism
number
modal-verb
...
```

(That's from the first page of the [tag list](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags); I probably missed some, and there are more on the subsequent pages.)

Probably these too, eh?

```
idiom
phrase 
expression
```

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I find `accent` to be an interesting one; to me, `accents` and `accent` are two different tags dealing with two different things.  `Accents` is talking about different types of accents — Southern, West Coast, Scottish, etc. On the other hand, `accent` would refer to the notion of *accent* in general.  Does anyone else feel that this is a valid distinction?  (Valid from the standpoint of tag usefulness, more than anything else...)

Comment: Actually, I feel this distinction is even more important for `numbers` vs. `number`.  One deals with 1, 2, 3... and the other deals with grammatical number and how it is expressed in English (e.g. number agreement in verbs).  But is this distinction useful for readers in general?

Comment: @Kosmonaut, I included `accents ` as `dialects` was already in plural... But admittedly I did stop to think in both of those cases and wasn't too sure. The distinctions you mention *might* be useful, but in practice I'm a bit doubtful if majority of users will ever recognise and appreciate them...

Comment: @Jonik: I agree that you may be completely right about that — the only thing that really concerns me is that, e.g., `accent` can technically refer to both notions of accent that I mentioned, whereas `accents` can only refer to types of accents.  I wonder if we suddenly stumbled upon a good reason to use all singulars instead?  (I really hesitate to say this since I have just gone through and updated a bunch of tags :)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Heh, perhaps. :) But I'd say let's go with plural for now, in most cases at least. If that proves to be too problematic, we can always change the policy (& retag again) later.

Comment: @Jonik: I agree... that is probably the most reasonable thing to do for now.

Comment: Marking this long ago complete thanks to @Kosmonaut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no objections, I will do this.

Comment: no objections here

Comment: @Kosmonaut - you guys *do* have access to the automated retag tools, right? It appears (from your recent edits) as if you're retagging manually...

Comment: @Jonik: Unless there is another way to do this that I don't know of, there must be at least one question with the plural form of the tag in order to apply the batch merge.  So I retagged one post with the plural tag in each case where one did not exist yet.

Comment: Ah, right. I've never used the moderation tools so I wasn't aware. :)

Comment: You missed `phrase`, eh? And one case where plural seems odd to me is, well, `plurals` (wouldn't `singular` and `plural` work the best in tags?). Anyway, thanks for retagging!

Comment: You are probably right about `plural`.  I will also change `phrase`.

Comment: Hmm... should there be a difference between `phrases` and `phrasing` (like, "how should this sentence be phrased" vs. "how is this phrase used")?