# Can [dictionary] and [dictionaries] be made synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[dictionary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) and [dictionaries](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionaries) don't have very many questions, but they do seem to cover the same topics. Is this a valid tag synonym?

Answer (score 4):

With tags, we generally use the plural form, but in this case I think [dictionary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) makes more sense.
I would make [dictionaries](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionaries) a synonym of [dictionary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary), and then merge the first tag with the second one, to make all the questions tagged [dictionaries](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionaries) appear as tagged [dictionary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary).

Comment: I personally don't mind either way, but why does [tag:dictionary] make more sense than [tag:dictionaries]?

Comment: You normally use _dictionary_ in phrases like "let's see what the dictionary says," even if you actually have two dictionaries to consult. I could be wrong, but that is what I think.

Answer (score 0):

Why not making always the singular as a synonym of the plural: noun vs nouns, verb vs verbs, etc.
We can't expect from the new users to know which one to use: the singular or the plural.

Comment: I think the way synonyms work is that if someone tags a question, say, [tag:noun], then it will show up as [tag:nouns] if they are synonyms. It's more of a grouping mechanism.

Comment: @simchona I think that too. So, is there a problem with my suggestion?

Comment: Synonym tags are created if there is a need, not just to add a tag because you think that somebody could use the singular when we want to use the plural, or vice versa. If there are users that keep using two different tags with the same meaning, then that is the case of making a tag synonym of the other one.

Comment: @Bogdan the singular is *usually* made synonym of the plural, but I shy away from saying "always" in case some other case arises in which the opposite should hold

Comment: @simchona if the singular is always made synonym of the plural, why do you ask this question?

Comment: @kiamlaluno if the tag-conscious people keep an eye every time a potential singular/plural synonym appears, no problem.

Comment: To notice also that a synonym tag is not created right after that tag is used in a question; it is normally created when more than a user use the tag for more than one question. Also, you don't make [tag:grammar] a synonym of [tag:grammaticality] just because users keep using [tag:grammar] instead of [tag:grammaticality].

Comment: @bog because I don't have enough rep in the tags to suggest a synonym

Answer (score 0):

I have, with slight reservations, made [dictionaries](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionaries) the master tag in this merge, for several reasons:

- [dictionaries](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionaries) has been favored over [dictionary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) by a factor of 8.
- Unlike, say, [indefinite-article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indefinite-article), there are many dictionaries in the English-speaking world.
- Existing questions rarely seem to ask about a specific dictionary; rather, they ask about either multiple dictionaries or dictionaries in general.
- We traditionally favor the [plural form of a tag](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-we-prefer-singular-or-plural-in-tags) in any case.
- @kiamlaluno's argument is not extremely persuasive. If I have multiple dictionaries, but I'm not referring to any in particular, I might use the singular. But if I want to consult all of them, I would probably use the plural.

Nonetheless, I'm open to reversing the synonym if there is a good reason.

Comment: My point is exactly that: you are not referring to any in particular. Anyway, I don't find any particular difference between using [tag:dictionary] or [tag:dictionaries]; I said what I think was the more correct to use. Users can still vote the one they prefer, if they feel the need.